Let $(x_t: t\geq 0) $ be the Brownian motion. $E(f| x_t)=0$ implies $f=0$?
Let $(x_t: t\geq 0)$ be the standard 1-dimensional Brownian motion on the Wiener space $(\Omega, \Sigma, d\mu)$. We assume $\Sigma$ is the (complete) $\sigma$-algebra generated by all $(x_t: t\geq 0)$. And we denote by $\sigma(x_t)$ the (complete) sub $\sigma$-algebra generated by $x_t$.

Suppose $f\in L^1(\Omega)$ such that for all $t\geq 0$ the conditional expectation $$\mathbb E(f| \sigma(x_t))=0.$$ Can we conclude that $f=0$?

If we replace $\sigma(x_t)$ by the (complete) sub $\sigma$-algebra generated by $(x_s: 0\leq s\leq t)$. Then the similar statement is true by Martingale convergence theorem.

$f$ can be independent of $(x_t)_{t \ge 0}$ with mean $0$. Why should $f$ be $0$?

I think you should add the condition that $f$ is measurable w.r.t $\sigma(x_t: t \ge 0)$

@geetha290krm Thank you for your comment! I will add this condition in my post.

Corrected answer:
Write $x=(x_t: t\geq 0)$ and define $f(x):=(2x_1-x_2)(x_3-x_2)$.
Consider the two sigma-fields $G=\sigma(x_t: t\le 2)$ and $H=\sigma(x_t: t \ge 2)$.
Clearly $E(f|G)=(2x_1-x_2)E(x_3-x_2|G)=0$. Moreover,
$E(f|H)=(x_3-x_2)E(2x_1-x_2|H)=0$,
since given $H$, the two variables $x_1$ and $x_2-x_1$ are independent standard normals conditioned to have sum $x_2$, so their conditional means must be equal by symmetry.
Each $x_t$ is measurable with respect to either $H$ or $G$, so the tower property of conditional expectations yields that $E(f|x_t)=0$ for all $t$.
P.S.  I initially misread the assumption.

Thank you for your answer. But can you make it more precisely? Here $\sigma(x_t)$ is the complete sub $\sigma$-algebra generated by the single function $x_t$, not the family $(x_s: 0\leq s\leq t )$. So $\sigma(x_t)$ is not increasing.

Answer corrected- I initially misread the hypothesis.
